# Why must the charger be rated 24W or higher instead of 21W or higher to minimize the charging duration of a Pixel 6?

Tags: charging, google-pixel-6, usb-power-delivery

I read on [androidcentral.com](https://www.androidcentral.com/which-fast-chargers-work-google-pixel-6-and-6-pro#:%7E:text=Best%20answer%3A%20In%20order%20to,the%20charger%20and%20the%20phone.):

> **In order to attain the maximum charging speed of 21W on your Pixel 6** (23W on Pixel 6 Pro), the **charger must** support Power Delivery (PD, Programmable Power Supply (PPS), and **be rated to 24W or higher**. You also need an e-marked cable that can negotiate the exact current between the charger and the phone.

Why must the charger be rated 24W or higher instead of 21W or higher?

Comment: Based on: https://www.androidauthority.com/fast-charging-explained-2-889780/ it just be as simple as adding a performance margin since the PPS may vary slightly.

Comment: On electronic devices it is not the best idea to run it at 100% of it's specification, especially considering that al lot charger are cheap China products that may get 100% of their power but only reliable on "Sundays in leap years"...